# Python pdb for a background process

Tags: python, unix, process

I have a python process, spawning multiple background processes. I am currently seeing one/many of the background process get stuck in deadloop or they are becoming irresponsive.

I want to attach a debugger to the background process. So, I can figure out what is going wrong. I have registered a signal handler for my background process (SIGUSR1) which I sets pdb trace.

I am sending the signal from another console to the background process, whenever it hangs.  However, I don't see any terminal which can help me debug the code.

Am I doing something wrong? or is there a better way to attach a debugger to background python process.

I am running on MAC and so using gdb is not straight forward.

```
  def installHandlers():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,debugHandle)

   def debugHandle(sig,frame):                                                          
     global processLog
     processLog.info("got the SIGUSR1")                                               
     import pdb                                                                       
     pdb.Pdb().set_trace(frame)
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because Python closes stdin of the parent process in the multiprocessing.Process._bootstrap(). Therefore pdb.set_trace() doesn't work in child processes. 
It usually fails with error. Maybe you don't see error because you redirect stdout somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is a clone of pdb, imaginatively called [pdb-clone](https://bitbucket.org/xdegaye/pdb-clone/wiki/Home), which allows for [debugging of background processes](https://bitbucket.org/xdegaye/pdb-clone/wiki/RemoteDebugging.md).

You simply add `from pdb_clone import pdbhandler; pdbhandler.register()` to the code for the main process, and then you can start pdb with `pdb-attach --kill --pid PID`.